# Inserting Data using join in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hi I have two Tables and after Join I want to Insert Data into Third Tables. Problem I am facing is I have to create multiple records based on the value of Join.

```
Table 1
A     B
-------
1     X
2     y
3     x

Table 2
A     C
-------
1     Y
2     N
3     Y
```

I need to join Table 1 and Table 2 on Column A and Based on value of Column C in Table 2 I need to insert Records in Table 3 
Rule 
If Column C value is 'Y' then insert 3 Records as  'Red','Green','Blue'
If Column C value is 'N then insert 2 records as 'White','Black'

So Result should be

```
Table 3 
A      D
-----------
1     Red
1     Green
1     Blue
2     White
2     Black
3     Red
3     Green
3     Blue
```

Can you let me know how to achieve this using hiveql ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do a join here since you're not using column B from Table 1. Can you clarify why a join is needed here?

Comment: Beacuse I am relying on value of column C which is in Table 2 . Table 1 does not have it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third table Color

```
Table Color
------------------
 Flag Color
 Y    Red
 Y    Blue
 Y    Green
 N    White
 N    Black
```

Now you can join them easily

```
Select * from Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.A = T2.C
JOIN COLOR C
  ON T2.C = C.Flag
```